# altGR not working on flash on Chrome PC

Tags: google-chrome

I made a flash file with a textbox in it, strangely on Chrome on windows altGR is not working, so it is impossible to make @ symbol.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Giuseppe

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem. Remove wmode : "transparent" from the params.